# How to select at most N records for a given value of a column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called NewsArticles having columns ID, LanguageID, Date, Title, ArticleContent. I want to create a view which selects the 5 most recent news articles of *each* language in the database.

For example, if I have 3 languages, say, English, French and German, the query should return 15 records, containing the 5 latest English news articles, the 5... you get the picture. How can I construct such a query?

***For each*** unique LanguageID in NewsArticles, return top 5 records ordered by Date descending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple with CTE.

```
;with x as 
(
    select ID, LanguageID, Title, Date,
            row_number() over ( partition by LanguageID order by Date DESC  ) as position
    from NewsArticles
)
select * from x 
where Position < 6
```

Comment: Would prefer to use joins if possible.

Comment: May I ask why? CTEs are extremely powerful and probably the best thing MS ever added to TSQL.

Comment: @Jake, there's no advantage to using joins. @Pavel's answer is definitely the best way to do this. It's the fastest, cleanest, and most manageable.

Comment: For portability reasons - I may want to do the same thing in MySQL or Oracle. I'll accept your answer though, thanks for your time.

Comment: The only fractional optimization you could make is to say "where Position <= 5".

Comment: @IanC: <= 5 is more readable, but there is no performance benefit (even in ASM, jl/jle are identical speedwise)

Comment: @Pavel true for ASM. However, this is not true for indexes. See "Symbol Operator" here: http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/. Like I said, this is *fractional* :).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW Top5Articles
AS     
    SELECT top 5 * FROM LatestNews WHERE LanguageID = 1 order by createdontime desc // latest 5 English news articles
    union
    SELECT top 5 * FROM LatestNews WHERE LanguageID = 2 order by createdontime desc
    union
    SELECT top 5 * FROM LatestNews WHERE LanguageID = 3 order by createdontime desc
```

Assuming you have a createdontime column with the article created on time.

union will give you all the selects back in one result set.

Comment: Actually, what I want is to construct a view which aggregates the latest 5 news articles of each language, **however many there happen to be in the database**, not just English, French and German.

Comment: To get all languages I would build up the sql required using a cursor and then exec the string.

Comment: Couldn't that be better achieved with joins?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible with joins.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this -

```
select *
from LatestNews
where (
   select count(*) from LatestNews as A
   where A.LanguageID = LatestNews.LanguageID 
) <= 5 order by Date DESC;
```